# Why is it saying my class cannot be found when I try to import it, when it's clearly in the sidebar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios6

I get this error:

[image]

What's going on? It just randomly stopped working, despite ArticleCell.h being right there.

Comment: are you importing RootViewController.h in ArticleCell.h

Comment: Probably not, and, even if you were, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: When importing, did you remember to add your app as the target?

Comment: Make sure the file `ArticleCell.h` is in your source folder not somewhere else.

Comment: If Xcode didn't randomly stop working occasionally I'd suspect it was broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that when you added the file originally, **you added it as a reference only** (rather than copying it). When you later moved your project, or the file that the reference points to, XCode no longer knows where to look for it

Re-add the file to your project, **making sure to check the box to make a copy as well**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Select your .m file from your left panel then *Show File Inspector* for right panel for that file.
[image: Refer this image]

Check whether that checkmark against your project target is checked or not. If not then check it.

One more thing:

While importing, you have to cross check whether you are copying this file to target.

Then clean your project and try with re-building.

Comment: The target membership has nothing to do with header (.h) files. When you forget to add a source (.m) file to the target you get a linking error but the compiler doesn't complain about missing header file.